# Change popup width based on specific container

Tags: html, css

I have a popup that has two containers:

1. text-container
2. buttons-container

The popup has width of 370px and the buttons appear below the text.

The width of the popup can be changed **only in a case** that there is long text in the buttons that cause the popup width to grow (the buttons should appear in one row always).

If there is a long text in the text container, the popup width should remain 370px.

For example:

1. The popup width is 383px because of long text in buttons:
   [image]
2. The popup width is 370px (The buttons text can be displayed in 370px):
   [image]

This is my jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/fuzozehipo/1/edit?html,css,output

HTML:

```
<div class="popup">
  <div class="text-container">some text</div>
  <div class="buttons-container">
    <button>Button 1 with long long long long long long text</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.popup {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  min-width: 370px;
}

.text-container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: no use of javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [interesting Flex rendering trick](http://dcousineau.com/blog/2011/07/14/flex-box-prevent-children-from-stretching/) to make the text not expand the parent by setting the child's width to `0`. Then just set `min-width: 100%` to ensure it takes up the full width of the parent container, which is now controlled only by the width of the buttons.

```css
.popup {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 370px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.text {
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

button + button {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla at porta sapien. Quisque sapien justo, fringilla consectetur molestie eu, hendrerit vehicula purus. Pellentesque ac ante urna.
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button>Really long text that will make the buttons push out the parrent div</button>
    <button>text</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing and thanks for the link!
I will give you the bounty tomorrow (I can award it 24 hours after I started it).

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something like

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  min-width: 370px;
}

.buttons-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.buttons-container > button {
  flex: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.buttons-container > button:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.text-container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the text, is is expected that `.popup` grows with the text because it is an `inline-block` element, so `width: 100%;` doesn't behave like you would want it. Since your value of `370px` is hard-coded, I see no issue in reusing it in your ruleset for the `.text-container` as part of a `max-width` rule. Although, it seems you have a `padding: 30px;` rule on your screenshots, so if you're using `box-sizing: border-box`, compensate for `.popup`'s padding by making `.text-container`'s `max-width` `310px`, which is the `width` - `padding` on each side.

For the buttons, use `white-space: nowrap;` on your `.buttons-container` to keep yours buttons on the same line, although the aforementioned behaviour of `.popup`'s `inline-block` should take care of it by itself.

```css
.popup {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  min-width: 370px;
}

.text-container {
  max-width: 370px; /* Compensate for the padding if using box-sizing: border-box */
}

.buttons-container {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <div class="text-container">some text that is also white long but that goes to the next line when it reaches a certain width</div>
  <div class="buttons-container">
    <button>Button 1 with longer text</button>
    <button>Button 2 with some text as well</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @chriskirknielsen!

It's so close but it wraps the text although there is another space to put text.

I think that "line when it" have enough space in order to be in the first line.. (It's because the max-width).

https://codepen.io/alonsh/pen/NYjZdo

Comment: @AlonShmiel try adding this: white-space: nowrap;